# How to set Airflow scheduler log file mode/permissions

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm running airflow 1.10.3, on Red Hat Linux.  I'm using a LocalExecutor, and the webserver and scheduler are both started via systemd.

The log files being generated by the scheduler are world-readable (i.e. mode "-rw-rw-rw-").  The log directories being created are "drwxrwxrwx".

This fails the security scans my organisation has in place.  I need to be able to restrict the permissions on these files.

The umask in /etc/profile is 077.  I've also added `UMask=0007` to both the systemd unit files for the services.  However, although this seems to be working for the logs in the dags/logs/scheduler/ directory, it is not affecting the DAG run logs.

```
[root@server logs]# ls -la s3_dag_test/
total 4
drwxrwxrwx.  4 airflow airflow   54 Aug  7 17:35 .
drwxrwx---. 46 airflow airflow 4096 Aug  7 20:00 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  5 airflow airflow  126 Aug  7 17:37 bash_test
drwxrwxrwx.  5 airflow airflow  126 Aug  7 17:29 check_s3_for_file_in_s3
[root@server logs]# ls -la s3_dag_test/bash_test/2019-08-07T17\:29\:27.988953+00\:00/
total 12
drwxrwxrwx. 2 airflow airflow   19 Aug  7 17:35 .
drwxrwxrwx. 5 airflow airflow  126 Aug  7 17:37 ..
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 airflow airflow 8241 Aug  7 17:35 1.log
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too late to be a helpful answer for you, but I had the exact same issue. My organization raised the permissions of the Airflow log directories as a security finding. I likewise checked the umask, to no avail.

I did manage to find this:

https://anoopkm.wordpress.com/2020/03/26/world-readable-airflow-dag-logs-issue/

In a nutshell, it looks like Airflow hard-codes the permissions used for creating files and folders.

I edited this Python file: `venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/log/file_task_handler.py` and changed lines 242 and 247 to use the `0o770` and `0o660` instead of `0o777` and `0o666` for creating folders and files, respectively. Then I manually triggered a DAG and checked the folder permissions. The newest log folder no longer had global rwx permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us know how airflow is installed as normal user or root user

Comment: Hi, the install creates an airflow user in an airflow group, and that's the context it runs under.  The logs are owned by that user (you can see that in the output in my question), but the permissions are too lax.

It's installed in a python 3.6 virtualenv, and runs as a systemd service.

I see the same in airflow 1.10.4

Comment: I tried setting a ACL on the logs folder - that actually restricted the permissions on the sub-directories, but the files themselves are still rw-rw-rw.  Is there something in the code explicitly setting these permissions?